# Find Fourier series coefficients of $f(x)$.

Tags: analysis, fourier-series

$T=2$
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{$-\frac12\le x \le\frac12$} \\[2ex]
|2x|, & \text{$\frac12 < x \le1\frac12$}  \\
\end{cases}$$

The image:

[image]

I found that $a_0=\frac12$. Since function is even, $b_n=0$.

However, I struggle one $a_n$. Here's how I try to find it:

$$a_n=\frac1l\int_{-l}^lf(x)cos(n\pi x)dx=\int_\frac{-1}2^\frac12|2x|cos(n\pi x)dx + \int_0^1cos(n\pi x)dx$$.

But in the end, I get ssomething like $sin(\frac{n\pi}2)$ which is indeterminate as $n$ varies.

Could you please help me? Is there a mistake somewhere or am I trying to solve this in a incorrect way?

And also there's another task. Write partial sum of members of Fourier series, whose coefficients' absolute value is more than $0,15$. How do I proceed here?

Comment: Provide a link to the graphics, I'll add it.

Comment: No link, would picture do?

Comment: Upload the pic to [imgur](http://imgur.com/), and send me the link.

Comment: Here it is http://imgur.com/BAknqGC

Comment: See the question now.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** You only need to solve the indefinite integral $$\int x\cos(ax)$$
where $a$ is a constant.

You can solve this integral using integration by parts.

**Hint 2:** For your integral remember to divide the integral to two integrals (where the sign of $x$ is known)

Comment: @Modestas_S - I mean that you can calculate the definite integral after you have solved the indefinite integral. But all the hard work is doing this integral

Comment: But there should be $|2x|$ instead of $x$, right?

Comment: @Modestas_S - If you do the integral from $-0.5$ to $0$ and from $0$ to $0.5$ then you don't need the absolute value since the sign of $x$ is know in those intervals

Comment: Maybe there is another solution?